# Undefined property in laravel framework accessor calling belongsTo

Tags: laravel, accessor, belongs-to

I need your help.
I'm working with Laravel Framework and I have a trouble with a belongsTo relationship.
My project have to tables, address book and delivery types, the columns in tables are:

**address_book**
id
name
mail
delivery_1
deliverytype_id_1
delivery_2
deliverytype_id_2
...

**delivery_types**
id
name
...

The code of delivery types model is this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DeliveryType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'delivery_types';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

This is the address book model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AddressBook extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'address_book';  // table
    protected $guarded = ['id'];    // primary key
    protected $appends = ['delivery', 'actions'];   // accessors

    protected $delivery = '';

    public function del1() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\DeliveryType', 'deliverytype_id_1', 'id')->withDefault();
    }

    public function del2() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\DeliveryType', 'deliverytype_id_2', 'id');
    }


    /**
    * Accessor: get the actions column information.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getActionsAttribute() {
        $actions = '<a href='. route('admin.addressbook.show', $this->id) .'>'.
                    'show<i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view contact"></i></a>';
        return $actions;
    }

    /**
    * Accessor: get the deliveries information.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getDeliveryAttribute () {
        $deliveries = [
            ['val' => $this->delivery_1, 'type' => $this->del1()->name], //row error
            ['val' => $this->delivery_2, 'type' => $this->del2()->name]
        ];

        foreach($deliveries as $delivery) {
            $this->delivery = (strlen($delivery['val']) > 0) ? 
                $this->appendString($this->delivery, '<strong>'.$delivery['type'].'</strong> '.$delivery['val']) : 
                $this->delivery;
        }
        return $this->delivery;
    }

    protected function appendString(string $str, string $val) {
        return (strlen($str) > 0) ? $str.'<br>'.$val : $val;
    }
```

In the html page the data is loaded through ajax call to the controller function. This is the code of function:

```php
public function data(Request $request) {

        // Init data
        $this->addressbooks = AddressBook::get(
                ['address_book.id',
               'address_book.name',
               'address_book.email',
               'address_book.delivery_1',
               'address_book.delivery_2');

        // Return json array
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        return $this->addressbooks;
    }
```

When the page call the function through ajax, the framework return the error "Undefined property" in the accessor `getDeliveryAttribute`, where I try to call relationship belongs to about delivery type `ID` and its reference in the delivery types table.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance to those who can help me.

Comment: `$this->del1()->name` should be `$this->del1->name`. When using relations, you get the related model instance by using `$this->del1`, and you get the query builder by using `$this->del1()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using $this-del1->name the error is gone, but value is empty even if the relationship exists. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try to `dd($this->del1)` to see if other values are there

Comment: Because you are using `withDefault()`, it's returning empty `name` if relation is not found. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#default-models).

Comment: I can' use dd because the function is called by ajax. Trying to write logs (Log::info('delivery type: '.$this->del1)) the result is local.INFO: delivery type: []

Comment: Even if you are using ajax, you can still inspect the response in chrome/firefox devtools. Look for the network panel once you open the devtools, trigger ajax call and look at the response. If it's a **GET** method, you can also open the link directly in new tab.

Comment: If I try dd about var in controller after I called the model, the value of delivery types table the value is shown correctly

Comment: Also, because you have `getDeliveryAttribute` Accessor, you should rename the `protected $delivery = '';`. I didn't test what would happen, but it could create you bugs down the line.

Comment: So it's working?

Comment: The result in devtools is this:
id 3
name Treutel
mail lblock@gmail.com
delivery_1 694-418-7757
delivery_1_name Mobile
delivery_2 726.748.9925 x7292
delivery_2_name Phone
delivery_3 1-917-795-7460 x1898
delivery <strong></strong> 694-418-7757<br><strong></strong> 726.748.9925 x7292<br><strong></strong> 1-917-795-7460 x1898<br><strong></strong> +1-650-714-1472
actions <a href=http://example.com/admin/addressbook/show/3>show<i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view contact"></i></a>

Comment: In the delivery accessor the value is empty. The trouble is if I try to call function with belongsTo from the same model. Trying to call accessor from controller, works correctly.

Comment: Can you try removing `protected $guarded = ['id'];` from both models? Not sure if this could create problems while laravel tries to return related models...

Comment: And, as I said, remove `protected $delivery = '';` variable. Because you defined  accessor `getDeliveryAttirbute()`, calling `$this->delivery` will call that method, so it can create you problems later (I'm not sure which ones, but make sure to avoid naming colisions)

Comment: Also, in accessors you should avoid "side-effect" of setting values of `$this->delivery = ...`. Accessor should take the value and return transformed value.

Comment: I have removed protected $guarded = ['id']; and change protected $delivery = ''; in protected $delInfo = ''; but the error is still present. I don't understand when you say "side-effect", can you explain me?

Comment: Update the answer with new code :)

Comment: From the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) __Accessors allow you to format Eloquent attribute values when you retrieve them on model instances__ . They should take the value and do some transformation on that value. And that's it. And in your example, calling `$this->delivery` or `$this->dellInfo` would return the same result anyway... You should use local variable in that method.

Comment: I wrote the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write the AddressBook model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AddressBook extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'address_book';  // table

    //protected $guarded = ['id'];    // primary key

    // always load these accessors
    protected $appends = [
        'delivery',
        'actions',
    ];

    protected $mail    = '';

    // No need for $delInfo, use $this->delivery (same data)
    // protected $delInfo = '';

    public function category() {
        /*
            You can use `AddressBookCategory::class` instead of `'App\DeliveryType'`

            http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name

            Because models are in the same napespace, we don't need to write \App\AddressBookCategory
         */
        return $this->belongsTo(AddressBookCategory::class, 'address_book_category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function deliveryType1() {
        return $this->belongsTo(DeliveryType::class, 'deliverytype_id_1', 'id')
                    /*
                        Specify empty string for the name, so that when we access
                        $this->deliveryType1->name it's equal ''
                     */
                    ->withDefault(['name' => '']);
    }

    public function deliveryType2() {
        return $this->belongsTo(DeliveryType::class, 'deliverytype_id_2', 'id')
                    ->withDefault(['name' => '']);
    }

    /**
    * Accessor: get the actions column information.
    *
    * Access by using: $this->action
    * 
    * @return string
    */
    public function getActionsAttribute() {
        // moved this into multi line, easier to read
        return '<a href='. route('admin.addressbook.show', $this->id) .'>'
                 .'show'
                 .'<i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view contact"></i>'
              .'</a>';
    }

    /**
    * Accessor: get the deliveries information
    *
    * Access by using: $this->delivery
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getDeliveryAttribute () {
        // I've updated logic here, it should be easier to read...
        $delivery = [];

        if ( ! empty($this->delivery_1) ) {
            $delivery[] = '<strong>'.$this->deliveryType1->name.'</strong> '.$this->delivery_1;
        }

        if ( ! empty($this->delivery_2) ) {
            $delivery[] = '<strong>'.$this->deliveryType2->name.'</strong> '.$this->delivery_2;
        }

        // join array elements with a string `<br>`
        return implode('<br>', $delivery);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and for spend your time. Unfortunately accessor continues to display only fields delivery_1 and delivery_2, but not related delivery tipes from belongsTo. I'm honestly at my wits' end.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would cause problems, I even created the tables for models `AddressBook` and `DeliveryType`, inserted dummy data in both tables and a test route to see what's returned. I see all fields... Did you check you database records in both tables? For the keys `address_book.deliverytype_id_1` and `address_book.deliverytype_id_2`, do you have records in table `delivery_types` (make sure you didn't delete those rows by accident)